# Craft 3 - Can't access the craft() in plugin controller

Tags: plugin-development, categories, craft3

I'm making a Craft 3 plugin to read a CSV file and insert the data as Categories.

I used [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/) to scaffold my plugin.

I can't access `craft()` in my controller (ImportCsvController.php).

**My controller action:**

```
    public function actionDoSomething()
    {
      $categoriesGroups = craft()->categories->getAllGroups();
      return json_encode("hi");
    }
```

**My namespacing:**

```
<?php


namespace workyard\csvtocategoryimporter\controllers;
use workyard\csvtocategoryimporter\Csvtocategoryimporter;
use craft\web\Controller;
use Craft;
```

**The error message:**

```
Call to undefined function workyard\csvtocategoryimporter\controllers\craft()
```

Any ideas why I can't access craft(). Do I have to "use" something in the namespace section?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`craft()` is gone in Craft 3; instead you will be accessing `Craft::$app->` for most things. I'd suggest generating your Craft 3 plugin scaffolding at [pluginfactory.io](https://pluginfactory.io/), and if you leave code comments on, it'll give you some hints on how to do stuff like this.

This article might also be helpful to you: [So You Wanna Make a Craft 3 Plugin?](https://nystudio107.com/blog/so-you-wanna-make-a-craft-3-plugin)

Comment: In addition to this really good answer I would like to leave this link to the official documentation https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/README.md and this link https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/v3/en/updating-plugins.md for the most important changes for plugin development